# Node.js oracle driver - multiple updates

Tags: node.js, oracle

So I've set up a node.js backend that is to be used to move physical items in our warehouse. The database hosting our software is oracle, and our older version of this web application is written in PHP which works fine, but has some weird glitches and is slow as all hell.

The node.js backend works fine for moving single items, but once I try moving a box (which will then move anything from 20-100 items), the entire backend stops at the .commit() part.

Anyone have any clue as to why this happens, and what I can do to remedy it? Suggestions for troubleshooting would be most welcome as well!

Code:

```
function move(barcode,location) {
var p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
  console.log("Started");
  exports.findOwner(barcode).then(function(data) {
    console.log("Got data");
    // console.log(barcode);
    var type = data[0];
    var info = data[1];
    var sql;
      sql = "update pitems set location = '"+location+"' where barcode = '"+barcode+"' and status = 0"; // status = 0 is goods in store. 
    ora.norway.getConnection(function(e,conn) {

      if(e) {
        reject({"status": 0, "msg": "Failed to get connection", "error":e});
      }
      else {
        console.log("Got connection");
        conn.execute(sql,[],{}, function(err,results) {
          console.log("Executed");
          if(err) {
            conn.release();
            reject({"status": 0, "msg": "Failed to execute sql"+sql, "error": err});
          }
          else {
            console.log("Execute was successfull"); // This is the last message logged to the console. 
            conn.commit(function(e) {
              conn.release(function(err) {
                  console.log("Failed to release");
              })
              if(e) {
                console.log("Failed to commit!");
                reject({"status": 0, "msg": "Failed to commit sql"+sql, "error": e});
              }
              else {
                console.log("derp6");
                resolve({"status": 1, "msg": "Relocated "+results.rowsAffected+" items."});
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that your code is open to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Even more so since you posted it online. ;)

I recommend updating your statement to something like this:

```
update pitems 
set location = :location 
where barcode = :barcode 
  and status = 0
```

Then update your conn.execute as follows:

```
conn.execute(
    sql,
    {
        location: location, 
        barcode: barcode
    },
    {}, 
    function(err,results) {...}
);
```

Oracle automatically escapes bind variables. But there's another advantage in that you'll avoid hard parses when the values of the bind variables change.

Also, I'm happy to explore the issue you're encountering more with commit. But it would really help if you could provide a reproducible test case that I could run on my end.

Comment: Dan is right: use binds. The original PHP may have been slow because bind variables weren't being used.

Comment: Hi Dan, apologies for not coming back to you sooner. This is by no means production ready code, and will naturally be escaped. I threw it together quick and dirty for our UI designers to mock something up and run tests towards. As for a test case - I've ran several random updates now, and this issue occurs every time I run more than 5-10 updates in a for loop. I believe it's because of node and it's asynchronous nature and oracle basically not being able to handle all the incoming queries. For now, autocommit has solved my problem though (all checks are ran prior to the updates).

Comment: rlweb, can you please provide a reproducible test case? I don't see an update loop in your code.

If you do go into a loop, I'd recommend using one of the series methods in the async library. If you just do a normal loop issuing executions on a connection, the connection will start to act as a serialization device (it will queue the executes). I think things will work better/more predictably if you control that yourself.

That may even be the cause of the problem.

Also, the exports in the middle of a function that declares/returns a promise is very hard to understand and follow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue on the database level, an update on multiple items without providing an ID is maybe not allowed.

You should do two things:

1) for debugging purposes, add console.log(JSON.stringify(error)) where you expect an error. Then you'll find the error that your database provides back

2) at the line that says

```
              conn.release(function(err) {
                  console.log("Failed to release");
              })
```

Check if err is defined:

```
      conn.release(function(err) {
          if(err){
              console.log("Failed to release");
          }
          else{console.log("conn released");}
      })
```

Comment: Added err-checks where it was missing without any results. It seems like it never gets to the .commit() section (or rather - never enters it).

Comment: Added autocommit to the section, and it worked perfectly. I'm not a huge fan of using autocommit, but seems to be the only choice at the moment.

Comment: ok..if that works for you :). Did you get the error stringified that is returned by the database server?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like similar to an issue that I'm having.  Node.js is hanging while updating oracle db using oracledb library.  It looks like when there are 167 updates to make, it works fine.  The program hangs when I have 168 updates.  The structure of the program goes like this:

When 168 records from local sqlite db, for each record returned as callback from sqlite: 1.) get an Oracle connection; 2.) do 2 updates to two tables (one update to each table with an autoCommit on the latter execute).  All 1st update completed but none can start the second update.  They are just hanging there.  With 167 records, they will run to completion.

The strange thing observed is that none of the 168 could get started on 2nd update (they finished 1st update) so some will have a chance to go forward to commit.  It looks like they are all queued up in some way.

Comment: Make sure you have enough threads to handle all the connections, otherwise you could be deadlocking yourself.  Bump UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE as needed.  The oracledb doc discusses this.